# Using the maven Maven-Mule-REST-Plugin

Tags: rest, maven, plugins, mule

I'm trying to use this plugin, but at loss trying to understand how to make maven use it. I would like to resolve it from Artifactory as opposed to via pluginRepository in the project pom.

https://github.com/NicholasAStuart/Maven-Mule-REST-Plugin

If I just run it after mvn package for example, it fails:

```
mvn mule-mmc-rest-plugin:deploy -Dname=muleAppName \
  -DmulepApiUrl=http://my.mmc.server:8080/mmc-console-3.4.0/api/repository \
  -Dversion=3.3.3 -Dusername=admin -Dpassword=pw

[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'mule-mmc-rest-plugin' in the current 
project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] 
available from the repositories [local (/root/.m2/repository), 
repo(http://my.artifactory:8081/artifactory/repo)] -> [Help 1]
```

In my pom I have added

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-mmc-rest-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </plugin>
```

In my artifactory I have the following artifact - this was uploaded by me

```
<groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
<artifactId>mule-mmc-rest-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
```

How can I make this third party plugin work? How do I fix this prefix thing?

Comment: It seems to work if I call mvn mule-mmc-rest:deploy - something about maven syntax for resolving prefixes.

Comment: I made it work using this http://java.dzone.com/articles/automated-deployment-mule and by working out the correct settings.xml for our internal build infrastructure.

Comment: It might worth adding your last comment as an answer (because it is)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by http://java.dzone.com/articles/automated-deployment-mule I found the following worked:

I downloaded the code for the plugin and mvn package'd it. I uploaded the target snapshot jar to artifactory, to a new repo for snapshots built by the team here. I made sure maven looks for plugins in snapshot based pluginRepositories too, using the stuff below.

In m2/settings.xml - as we want Artifactory to cache ALL artifacts and we do not want developer machines hitting the Internet for artifact resolution:

```
<mirrors>
  <mirror>
    <id>artifactory</id>
    <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://my.artifactory:8081/artifactory/repo</url>
  </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

And this too is required (literally). It is using Sonatype's suggested way to use a single repo (http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html)

```
<profiles> 
  <profile> 
    <id>artifactory-repos</id> 
    <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
    <!--all requests to artifactory via the mirror -->
    <repositories> 
      <repository> 
        <id>central</id>
        <!-- this is a bogus url - maven ignores it - dont change -->
        <url>http://central</url>
        <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
      </repository> 
    </repositories> 
    <pluginRepositories> 
      <pluginRepository> 
        <id>central</id>
        <url>http://central</url>
        <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
        <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
      </pluginRepository> 
    </pluginRepositories> 
  </profile> 
</profiles> 
<activeProfiles> 
  <activeProfile>artifactory-repos</activeProfile> 
</activeProfiles>
```

And finally, this added to the project pom to nail it:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mule.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>mule-mmc-rest-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>mule-deploy</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>deploy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <name>${artifactId}</name>
          <username>muleuser</username>
          <password>mulepass</password>
          <version>${version}</version>
          <serverGroup>Test</serverGroup>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

And finally, we are able to run

```
mvn install -DmuleApiUrl=http://my.mulemmc:8080/mmc-console-3.4.0/api
```

I externalised muleApiUrl as we have more than one mmc to deploy to.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who stumbles upon this, after getting the same error in the original question, I was also able to get the plugin goal to execute correctly by using `mvn com.github.nicholasastuart:mule-mmc-rest-plugin:deploy`.

It seems the instructions on the Github page don't quite match the actual syntax (internal repository configuration issues notwithstanding).